# can we deploy ".msi" package through azure CICD in On-premises VM?

Tags: azure-pipelines

We are able to build the application through visual studio 2019 build task and able to generate MSI artifacts. Now in release pipeline, we want to deploy that .msi package, i have used windows machine file copy task but it's not working. Can anyone please suggest me any possible ways to deploy .msi package ?

Comment: Hi, have you checked my answer, does it work on your side? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

The WindowsMachineFileCopy task copies the file on the local machine. You could refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/windows-machine-file-copy-v2?view=azure-pipelines) for more details.

> TargetPath - Destination Folder string. Required.
>
> Specifies the local path on the target machines or an accessible UNC
> path for copying the files from the source, like d:\fabrikam or
> \fabrikam\Web.

You could first publish you package to Azure DevOps as a feed. Following the steps described in Artifacts->Feed->Connect to feed->Universal Packages

```
az login
az artifacts universal publish --organization https://dev.azure.com/<YOUR_ORGANIZATION> --feed <FEED_NAME> --name <PACKAGE_NAME> --version <PACKAGE_VERSION> --description <PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION> --path <PACKAGE_DIRECTORY>
```

And then download the universal package in your release pipeline before you start to deploy using the Universal Packages task:

[image]

Choose the command as Download and set the required information.
[image]